# how to pass parameter to glue job using boto3 create_job programmatically

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-sdk, aws-glue

I am creating glue job using boto3 create job script and trying to pass default argument value to path location to run different s3 bucket files.

Below script is sample code, which will create glue ETL job. How to pass parameters to sourcepath using args?

Sample script:

```py
import boto3
import json
client = boto3.client('glue')
response = client.create_job(
   Name='jobname',
   Description='Glue Job',
   LogUri='s3://bucket/logs/',
   Role='arn:aws:iam::',
   ExecutionProperty={
       'MaxConcurrentRuns': 3
   },
   Command={
       'Name': 'glue',
       'ScriptLocation': 's3://bucketname/gluejob.py',
       'PythonVersion': '3'
   },
   MaxRetries = 1,
   Timeout=123,
   GlueVersion='3.0',
   NumberOfWorkers=2,
   WorkerType='G.1X',
   DefaultArguments = {'s3sourcepath':'s3://bucketname/csvfile.csv'}
   CodeGenConfigurationNodes = {
   'node-1':{
       'S3CsvSource': {
               'Name': 's3_source',
               'Paths': [
                   args['s3sourcepath'], ------ here how to pass default arguments 
               ],
               'Separator': 'comma',
               'QuoteChar': 'quote',
               'WithHeader': True,
               'WriteHeader': True
           }
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scenario 1 : Creating job using boto3 . (Problem here is argument / parameter unable to define in 'paths'. Scenario 2 : Glue job created with default getresolvedoption . Glue job script is not contains arguments / parameter. Expected result in glue script  getResolvedOptions(args,["JOB_NAME","s3sourcepath"]).

Answer (score 0):

You first need to retrieve the arguments that you have passed using getResolvedOptions. Something like this:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['s3sourcepath'])
```

Now you should be able to use
`args['s3sourcepath']`

You can read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-get-resolved-options.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i dont want to edit and add . if i add manually args = getResolvedoptions (sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME","s3sourcepath"]) then glue etl job will run and we can pass differnt location while running with parameter but without editing glue job , how can i get this from create_job script.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if this run-time parameters can be set while creating a Glue job.  Can you try to set run-time parameters when you call start_job_run().  You can refer here [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html) for code samples

```
response = client.start_job_run(
           JobName = 'my_test_Job',
           Arguments = {
             '--s3sourcepath':   's3 path',
              } )
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. Arguments are not set in the glue etl job so even if we pass in start_job run also will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the job command is given as `glue`.

```
Command={
   'Name': 'glue',
   'ScriptLocation': 's3://bucketname/gluejob.py',
   'PythonVersion': '3'
```

},

But the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_JobCommand.html) says it should be `glueetl`

```
Command={
       'Name': 'glueetl',
       'ScriptLocation': 's3://bucketname/gluejob.py',
       'PythonVersion': '3'
   },
```

Can you try with

```
'Name': 'glueetl'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).